# Drupal7 plupload not showing selector

Tags: drupal-7, plupload

[image]My Plupload is not showing the file selector/browser. It only shows the 'upload' button. I have cleared cache and run cron and have the same settings and same modules another site which is showing the file selector properly.I have the modules selected for plup, plupload, filefield_sources and filefield_sources_plupload, and the filesources selected in the content type What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit your status page, possibly the plupload plugin is not where it should be.

http://yoursite.com/admin/reports/status

Also check in the console of your browser for any javascript errors that could be interfering with the execution of plupload.

Finally check again the plupload config:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1647890

Hope that helps.

PD: Personally I had some issues working with Plupload module. For multiple uploads in Drupal you have many choices. The best in my opinion is this: https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget for files and for images this https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget

Comment: thank you - very helpful suggestion. Yes I've found in the reports that the plupload plugin isn't there/ working, will look into why now!

Comment: Cool! The status page is very helpful indeed.

Comment: yes, it turned out I did not have the plupload library version showing, and needed to downgrade it a previous plupload (1.58) that was less buggy, now the status report shows the plupload and the browser is showing fine.